# WooCommerce - Change "add to cart" button text to products with no price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to change the "add to cart" button text to "for more additional information" but i want the function to work only for products that didnt set any price at all.

so far i found those 2 snippets but i couldn't figure out how to combine them

1. this code will change the price for products without a price to text:

```
function add_inquiry_link_instead_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) {

        return '<span class="price_on_inquiry">TEXT TO CHANGE HERE</span>';

    }

    return $price;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'add_inquiry_link_instead_price', 100, 2 );
```

2.this code will change the "add to cart" button text to what i write

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  
function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'TEXT TO CHANGE HERE', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Comment: What would even be the point of only changing the button _text_, but leaving its _functionality_ in place? So I click on a button saying "for more additional information" now, and as a result, the product will be put into the cart. How exactly did this give me "more additional information" now?

Comment: The `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` filter does not pass a product to the callback function - but you should be able to access it the same way as was done here, https://gist.github.com/deckerweb/cf466e017fd01d503469#file-wc-custom-add-to-cart-texts-php-L16

Comment: actually, since the product doesn't have a price you cannot add it to cart. it will simply transfer you to the product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);

function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text($text, $product) {

    if ('' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price()) {
        $text = __('TEXT TO CHANGE HERE', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $text;
}
```

WooCommerce is passing the product with the corresponding product type add to cart text callback. See the sample from WooCommerce core for simple products below.

```
/**
     * Get the add to cart button text.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function add_to_cart_text() {
        $text = $this->is_purchasable() && $this->is_in_stock() ? __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', $text, $this );
    }
```